# Binding different control values by their name

Tags: orbeon

We are coding our form in Form Builder by binding different control values by their name. For example: [**formdata**](http://ideone.com/5mZp8q).
Actually we need xml data like that: [**outputdata.xml**](http://ideone.com/PZpNWa).
As you see in outputdata.xml, control with name `A_2` binded with control which name  is `B2`. An so on. A_3 with B3, ..., A_n with Bn (n - number)
We did this by using XSLT tranform technology. Calling jsp using workflow-button-send and HTTP service.
It's hard to coding our form. Because we can make a mistake. How can we make it easy. We are thinking about **auto name** for some section. 
For example: How can we do auto name for created controls in some section. (every control's name begins with A_1, A_2, A_3, and so on and respectively in different section controls names with B1, B2, B3, B4?

Or maybe is there any other technique to get data.xml like in outputdata.xml? Thank you in advance!
what about xpl processor?

Comment: Did you mean to link to an example of `outputdata.xml`?

Comment: @ebruchez, yes I did. Is it possible to add some attributes to controls from Form Builder? We need to bind some data to controls in Form Builder. Avernet recommend me to use XSLT to transform one xml to another. But it's very complicated. Because analytic may make a mistake when code names by typing(A_1, A_2, A_3, ...,A_n to bind with B1, B2, B3, ...,Bn. Do you understand me?

Comment: @ebruchez, for example: we give A_2 to one input control name and NKIPC="01112102" to value field. Then we made this section invisible. `<A_2>NKIPC="01112102"</A_2>`. `<B2>80</B2>` respectively with another contol. In output we get `<ITEM KCP="F262601" MKEI="469" PERIOD="2" NKIPC="01112102" KATO="193200000" DATA="2012-11-10" POK="80"/>`. We are binding control with name B to all controls(see outputdata.xml) `<B>KCP="F262601" MKEI="469" PERIOD="2"</B>`. It's our idea how we code form and bind xml elements. But it's complicated, because we have a very large form with big data. So I need help.

Comment: @ebruchez, Erik, I am still waiting for your answer.

Comment: @Bolatik I am a bit surprised to see `<B>KCP="F262601" MKEI="469" PERIOD="2"</B>` in the form data. This means you created a field named `B` and that users typed `KCP="F262601" MKEI="469" PERIOD="2"`. Wouldn't it make more sense to have instead 3 fields `KCP`, `MKEI` and `PERIOD`. Then you will have 3 elements in the XML, but those can be transformed in attribute by XSLT, after the data is collected.

Comment: @avernet, a couple of precisions:  - inputfield with name `<B>` is invisible. So it's an author type `<B>KCP="F262601" MKEI="469" PERIOD="2"</B>` in FB. -Actually we have given names `A_2, A_3, ..., B1, B2, B3` to bind `A_2` with `B2`.

Comment: @Bolatik, got it. In your auto-naming scheme, would you name the controls in order they appear? That is, controls in the first section are `A1`, `A2`, `A3`…, then in the second section, they are `B1`, `B2`, `B3`…? If that is the case, whatever names the elements have, it is relatively easy to write XSLT that renamed elements by following that convention.

Comment: @avernet, yes, you're right. Thank you. We may close a thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to avernet's answer, we have to write XSLT that renamed elements by following that convention.